# Combine index_col with converters in read_excel function

Tags: python, excel, pandas, indexing, format

I would like to know how I can combine the use of converters with use_col.
I have to format certain columns, one of these columns being the one selected to become the index. The problem is that when I select a certain column as an index, on that column the use of the converter is ignored:

```
>>>formatter = lambda x: '{:06d}'.format(x)
>>>df = pd.read_excel(path_to_file,
             sheet_name=None,
             converters={
                'ID':formatter,
                'A1':formatter
             },
             index_col='A1')
>>>df['Sheet0'].index
Int64Index([853, 242, 258, 867, 924, 943,  22, 297, 246, 690, 152, 455, 581,
        583, 968, 128, 155, 181],
       dtype='int64', name='A1')
```

For these cases, normally the "trick" that I use when I only need to read an excel sheet is to use set_index after having read the tables with the appropriate converters:

```
>>>df = pd.read_excel(path_to_file,
             sheet_name='Sheet0',
             converters={
                'ID':formatter,
                'A1':formatter
             }).set_index('A1')
>>>df.index
Index(['000853', '000242', '000258', '000867', '000924', '000943', '000022',
   '000297', '000246', '000690', '000152', '000455', '000581', '000583',
   '000968', '000128', '000155', '000181'],
  dtype='object', name='A1')
```

However, now I need to read several sheets of the excel book and in this way I would need to go through the dictation returned using set_index to each dataframe. I would like to know if there is a "better" way to perform such an operation without looping through the returned dict, ie using only read_excel:

```
>>>df = pd.read_excel(path_to_file,
             sheet_name=None,
             converters={
                'ID':formatter,
                'A1':formatter
             },
             index_col='A1')
>>>df['Sheet0'].index
Index(['000853', '000242', '000258', '000867', '000924', '000943', '000022',
   '000297', '000246', '000690', '000152', '000455', '000581', '000583',
   '000968', '000128', '000155', '000181'],
  dtype='object', name='A1')
```